# Android DFP banner ads - what size is returned?

Tags: android, google-dfp

[DFP documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/banner) states that I can use multiple ad sizes when requesting banner ads using setAdSizes() method like this:

```
PublisherAdView adView = new PublisherAdView(this);
adView.setAdSizes(AdSize.BANNER, new AdSize(120, 20), new AdSize(250, 250));
```

They also say that **If PublisherAdView changes size at refresh time, your layout should be able to automatically adapt to the new size.**

OK, but how do I find out what size was returned  by the server? I know that I can set an AdListener on the adView and get notified when the ad is loaded via callbacks like onAdLoaded(), onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode), etc. but none of them seem to offer an option to get the banner size returned by the server.